# Trim end of char *

Tags: c, char, trim

Having `char double[] = "1.2345678";`  , I have to trim all digits in 4nd place and above after the `.` in this `char *`  i.e make it to `"1.234"` .

Comment: Please don't attempt to use double as variable name. It's a keyword!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious solution is to replace a character by `NUL`, like so:

```
char *foo = strdup("1.2345678");   // FIXME: check return value
foo[5] = '\0';
```

Note that the exact position might differ, depening on how many digits appear before the '.' character.

Iterate over the string `foo`, change the state in `passed_dot` if you come across '.', and insert a `NUL` after 4 more characters:

```
char *p = foo;
int i = 0;
int passed_dot = 0;
while (p && *p) {
        if (*p == '.') passed_dot = 1;
        if (passed_dot) i++;
        if (i == 4) {
                *p = '\0';
                break;
        }

        p++;
}
```

If you can't afford to buy more RAM, you may `strdup()` the resulting string and `free()` the old one in order to save memory:

```
new_str = strdup(foo);   // and don't forget to check for NULL
free(foo);
```

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: Good hint! Edited my answer.

Comment: Note that the OP doesn't say anywhere that his string is dynamically allocated.  It may be a stack buffer.  In this case, there is no sensible way to reuse the memory for the chars past the nul.  Even if the string is dynamically allocated, it seems questionable whether the spike in memory use when you dynamically allocate a replacement justifies the small memory saving when you free the original.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, you can't modify a char literal. You need `foo` to be an array.

Comment: @Philip where do you inc the pointer on 'p' , it look on the first char only .

Comment: @unwind: Good hint! Edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Find the `'.'`, advance four steps, and put the string terminator there.

Watch out so you don't pass the string terminator yourself, if the number contains less than three digits after the dot.

To help you find the dot, look up the [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) function.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

```
char * double= "1.2345678";
```

declares a string literal.  This is const so can't be directly modified.  To get a modifiable string, you could declare it as

```
char double[] = "1.2345678";
```

or

```
char* double = strdup("1.2345678");
```

then insert a nul character as suggested in other answers.